# How to create a custom form with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a `form` using `flexbox` that will have two lines.

In the first one, all the `inputs` and content will be displayed. In the second one, I want to display the submit `button`.

```
+----------------+--------------------------+
|    CONTENT     |          INPUTS          |
+----------------+--------------------------+
|              SUBMIT BUTTON                |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Here is my code:

```css
html, body{
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}

#content{
   display: flex;
}
#divInside{
   position: relative;
   width: 200px;
   height: 155px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   margin: 10px;
}

#customForm{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

#wrapperName{
   flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form id="customForm" action="whatever" method="post">
    <div id="divInside"></div>
    <div id="wrapperName">
      <input class="textForm" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
      <input class="textForm" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description"><br>
    </div>
    <input id="buttonLogin" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

I tried wrapping the content in one div and the `inputs` in another to fill the full line but, as the first div (`#divInside`) has a fixed `width`, I do not know how to make the other div (`#wrapperName`) fill the rest of the line and force the `button` to move to the next line.

How can I force the `button` to the next line?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout is relatively simple with flex properties alone. No need for CSS positioning properties.

```css
#customForm {
    display: flex;              /* primary flex container */
    flex-wrap: wrap;            /* enable flex items to wrap */
}
#divInside {
    width: 200px;
    height: 155px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: flex;               /* nested flex container (for text alignment demo) */
    justify-content: center;     /* center text (optional) */
    align-items: center;         /* center text (optional) */
}
#wrapperName {
    flex: 1;                     /* consume all available space in the line */
    display: flex;             
    flex-direction: column;      /* stack flex items vertically */
    justify-content: center;     /* vertical alignment */
}
#buttonLogin {
    flex-basis: 100%;            /* force button to its own line; take full width */
}
```

```html
<form id="customForm" action="whatever" method="post">
  <div id="divInside">Content</div>
  <div id="wrapperName">
    <input class="textForm" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input class="textForm" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description">
  </div>
  <input id="buttonLogin" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The position property is to align with `absolute` positioning some elements inside the content div (I reduce here the amount of code). Thank you for the answer! It is similar of what I was looking for but not exactly. Anyway, with your solution you makes me clear my mind and get it :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can always force a flex item to the next row by enabling `wrap` on the container and making the item too wide to fit on the current line.

Comment: Yes, I had used it before but I forgot it. Thank you again for save my life one more time :)

Answer (score 0):

Changes:

- Moved submit button out of `#customForm`
- Made `#wrapperName`

  ```
  #wrapperName {
   flex: 1;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   align-items: space-around;
   justify-content: center;
  }
  ```
- Removed `#content` styles.
- Added the attribute `form="customForm"` so it belongs to the form while outside of the form.
- Blue dashed outline and visual changes to borders and colors are just for visual aid and are not necessary.

  ```css
  html, body{
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
  }

  #content{

  }
  #divInside{
     position: relative;
     width: 200px;
     height: 155px;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid red;
     background: rgba(255,0,0,.4);
     color: white;
     margin: 10px;
  }

  #customForm{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     outline: 1px dashed blue;
    
  }

  #wrapperName{
     flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: space-around;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="content">
    <form id="customForm" action="whatever" method="post">
      <div id="divInside"></div>
      <div id="wrapperName">
        <input class="textForm" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
        <input class="textForm" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description"><br>
      </div>
      
    </form>
    <input id="buttonLogin" type="submit" value="Submit" form="customForm">
  </div>
  ```